# Update file in each subdirectory with a specific name

Tags: powershell, batch-file, subdirectory

I have a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which pulls a file from a url using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) and then outputs/updates the file in a specific directory. But I have many of these directories, the only thing that changes about the path is numbers between `\command\` and `\setup\`. How would I get it to put the file in every folder automatically?

Essentially I would like to output the downloaded text file in each of the `install` [subdirectories](/questions/tagged/subdirectories) of that path.

Also how could I make it happen silently?

```
@echo off
echo !!! PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE AND UPDATE!!!
pause

powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/log/read.txt" -OutFile C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command\234235234\setup\install\read.txt 2>NUL >NUL

echo !!! DONE NOW !!!
echo !!! YOU CAN RE-OPEN NOW !!!
```

Comment: You will likely need to Get the .Fullpath of each Directory, then just copy your file to each of them. Download your file and Copy-Item to each directory in your array. The numbers don’t really matter? You just need the destinations.

Comment: i dont understand, i would like it to copy a file from one folder to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command\...\setup\install\     so the event i  get more folder added in that path i dont have to update the ,bat code again

Comment: @4DAWIN Why do you write a batch file of which lines are processed by `cmd.exe` containing as main line the execution of `powershell.exe`? Why do you not code a PowerShell script file *.ps1 which is executed by `powershell.exe`? Everything which can be done in a batch file using `cmd.exe` can be also done in a PowerShell script file using `PowerShell.exe`. I have not yet seen any real good reason for creating a hybrid batch file using `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` instead of doing everything with only PowerShell using a PowerShell script.

Comment: i didnt start the code and i am not experienced with this. The initial code works when the file path is absolute but for what i want to do with it, i was unable to figure what to do. If you think that there is a better way then I am all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for /d /r "dirname" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="install" echo %%a
```

may be useful to you.

Your requirement is unclear. Do you want to copy the file to the `install` subdirectories of `...\234235234\..` only, or of `...\*\...` ?

Replace `dirname` with the name of the starting directory, be it `...\234235234\..`  or `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command` and the command I have shown will report all of the `install` directories contained under `dirname`. All you need then do is to change the `echo` to an appropriate `copy` command - see `copy /?` from the prompt. You can suppress `copy`'s responses by appending `>nul 2>nul` (suppress messages and suppress error messages)

`for /d /r` with `*` as the list element will process a list of all subdirectories starting at the nominated directory. The `if` command selects only the leaf directories that match `install` in either case (/i)

---

Since

```
for /d /r ...
```

does nor detect hidden directories, another approach is

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad "dirname" ') do if /i "%%~nxa"=="sub1" echo %%a
```

Which in this case should be

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command" ') do if /i "%%~nxa"=="sub1" echo %%a
```

The `dir` command produces a list in `/b` basic (name-only) form, `/s` including subdirectories, `/ad` of directories only (names with the `directory` attribute set). This list is processed line-by-line by `for /f` without delimiters so the entire line (including spaces, if any) is assigned to `%%a` and displayed.

Comment: so essential i got 10 paths like this        C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command\234235234\setup\install\read.txt    the only different is id number. I want to update the text file in the install folder in each of those folders

Comment: Have you executed that command, replacing `dirname` with `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command` ? What were the results? To execute a command from the prompt, replace each `%%` with `%`.

Comment: echo !!! PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE AND UPDATE!!!
pause

powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/log/read.txt" -OutFile for /d /r "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="install" echo %%a >nul 2>nul  

echo !!! DONE NOW !!!
echo !!! YOU CAN RE-OPEN NOW !!!


@Magoo is this what i am suppose to put in the .bat file

Comment: No. omit the `>nul 2>nul `. That is the method for suppressing `copy`'s messages since you want the operation (once it starts working) to be silent. I might also be of advantage during this testing phase to add an additional `pause` line after the `for...` line. From what I can see, your `for` command is correctly-constructed.

Comment: hmm doesnt seem like its working i am checking the folders and nothing it being copied

Comment: Small steps. Does the above command report the locations of the `install` directories that exist under "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command" ? It should...

Comment: powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/log/read.txt" -OutFile C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command\234235234\setup\install\read.txt 2>NUL >NUL

so this command downloads the file from url and installs it in the folder or updates the text file to whatever text file is downloaded. That install folder is created when ever i install more instances of this program i use which is why the Id numbers are different in the path. So i would like to update that text file in all install folders at the end of that path when i run the .bat

Comment: Well, that repeats what you've already said. Using this command `for /d /r "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="install" echo %%a` - are all the target `...install` directory-names displayed?

Comment: when i run just that in a .nat nothing comes up for me

Comment: i can use copy paste that code in a new a text file     for /d /r "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\base\command" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="install" echo %%a and save the text file as.bat and it should work right

Comment: correct. The current objective is to locate the `...install` directories.

Comment: yeah nothing is is being loccated umm is it becauase the older is hidden?

Comment: Yes - a hidden directory would not be reported. I'll revise the `for` and edit my response after testing with a hidden directory.